# Why doesn't math.h define the reciprocal trig functions?

Tags: c, standards, trigonometry, math.h

I find little things like this throughout the C programming language; something that is very easy to provide, has very little chance of breaking old code, and has an obvious way to standardize it.  Is minimalism the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reciprocal, do you mean the arc functions? They're defined as `asin()`, `acos()` and `atan()` (and `atan2()`)

If you mean 1/cos(), 1/sin() and 1/tan(), implementing these functions is a trivial exercise, but dealing with error checking (sin() != 0, etc. etc.) is far more effort than it's worth for a major library.

Comment: Error checking is irrelevant. Library code routinely performs error checking. If what you say is true, why do libraries implement inverse trig for example?

Answer (score 5):

Because they're trivial to compute if you have the "standard" trig functions?